# Filtering spark dataframe with the special characters '??'

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below:

`|         token|
+--------------+
|         today|
|            ??|
|           ??|
|          good|`

Using `df.filter(col('token')=='??')`, I am only able to filter the first "??", but not the second one. Can someone give me some tips on filtering the second '??'?

Answer (score 0):

`df.filter(col('token').rlike('??\x1a'))`